# Setting List Metadata Navigation settings using CSOM

Tags: csom

How would I use the SharePoint CSOM to configure the Metadata navigation Settings for the documents list? This is for an online SharePoint instance and I haven't been able to find anything online for this, is this even possible?

This video shows roughly what I am trying to achieve using the client side object model.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqt99a6fEXU

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to add relevant code to this question.

```
private static void AddMetadataNavigationToDocLib(ClientContext ctx, List docLib)
{
    var rootWeb = ctx.Site.RootWeb;

    ctx.Load(rootWeb, p => p.AvailableFields);
    ctx.Load(docLib, p => p.RootFolder, p => p.RootFolder.Properties);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    if (rootWeb.AvailableFields.Any(p => p.InternalName.Equals(Common.Constants.TagsFieldName)))
    {
        var field = rootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(Common.Constants.TagsFieldName);

        ctx.Load(field, p => p.Id, p => p.InternalName, p => p.TypeAsString);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<MetadataNavigationSettings SchemaVersion='1' IsEnabled='True' AutoIndex='True'>");
        sb.Append("<NavigationHierarchies><FolderHierarchy HideFoldersNode='False' />");
        sb.AppendFormat("<MetadataField FieldID='{0}' FieldType='{1}' CachedName='{2}' CachedDisplayName='{3}' />", field.Id, field.TypeAsString, field.InternalName, field.InternalName);
        sb.Append("</NavigationHierarchies><KeyFilters /></MetadataNavigationSettings>");

        docLib.RootFolder.Properties["client_MOSS_MetadataNavigationSettings"] = sb.ToString();
        docLib.RootFolder.Update();
        docLib.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

From

https://srinivasananand.wordpress.com/2015/10/29/activating-document-lib-tree-navigation-using-csom/

PowerShell equivalent

```
function SetupDocumentTypeNavigation($webUrl, $listTitle)
{
    $context = GetContext $webUrl

    $web = $context.Web
    $list = $web.Lists.GetBytitle($listTitle)
    $listProps = $list.RootFolder.Properties
    $documentTypeField = $list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Document Type")

    $context.Load($web)
    $context.Load($list)
    $context.Load($listProps)
    $context.Load($documentTypeField)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    write-host ("Enabling Document Type Navigation..." + $nl)

    $sb = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
    $sb.Append("<MetadataNavigationSettings SchemaVersion='1' IsEnabled='True' AutoIndex='True'>") | Out-Null
    $sb.Append("<NavigationHierarchies><FolderHierarchy HideFoldersNode='False' />") | Out-Null
    $sb.AppendFormat("<MetadataField FieldID='"+$documentTypeField.Id+"' FieldType='"+$documentTypeField.TypeAsString+"' CachedName='"+$documentTypeField.InternalName+"' CachedDisplayName='"+$documentTypeField.InternalName+"' />") | Out-Null
    $sb.Append("</NavigationHierarchies><KeyFilters /></MetadataNavigationSettings>") | Out-Null

    $list.RootFolder.Properties["client_MOSS_MetadataNavigationSettings"] = $sb.ToString()
    $list.RootFolder.Update()
    $list.Update()

    $context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was trying to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is only available in (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement) API.
however this is possible through PS: http://get-spscripts.com/2011/03/configuring-metadata-navigation.html

However you can try

Try the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation namespace:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.navigation(v=office.15).aspx